# Select Customer before creating order pos odoo 16

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-16

I need help regarding javascript logic in odoo16.

First of all, when I start before creating an order, I need to show the PartnerListCream view to select the client before proceeding to create the order.

I got it to work, but now if the cashier has a pin it does not show me the view so I can add the cashier's pin and start the flow of selecting a customer and then creating the order attached to what I did.

```
odoo.define("pos_customer_required.ProductScreen", function (require) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("SE cargo3");
    const ProductScreen = require("point_of_sale.ProductScreen");
    const Registries = require("point_of_sale.Registries");
    const PartnerListScreen = require("point_of_sale.PartnerListScreen"); 
    const { useListener } = require("@web/core/utils/hooks");


    // Registries.Component.extend(ProductScreen, PosRequiredCustomerProductScreen,PartnerListScreen);

    const PosRequiredCustomerProductScreen = (ProductScreen) =>
        class extends ProductScreen {
            onMounted() {
              console.log("Start -----TESTT");
              if (this.env.pos.config.require_customer === "order") {
                this.onClickPartner();
              };
            }

        };


  
    Registries.Component.extend(ProductScreen, PosRequiredCustomerProductScreen);

    return PosRequiredCustomerProductScreen;
});
```

require_customer

require_customer is a parameter that I create as a configuration that if active, it is required to select a customer before creating the order and the onClickPartner method is native to Odoo, it is the event that simulates to open the view and select a customer.

Finally, as I mentioned, the view to select the customer appears before creating the order, but at no time does it now show me the view to place the cashier's pin.